# invokeOnClick error in c++

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

Here is my code:

```
if (r->Value == "Off"){
     if (checkBox1->Checked)
          checkBox1->Control::InvokeOnClick(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
}
else if (r->Value == "Off") {
     if (!checkBox1->Checked)
          checkBox1->Control::InvokeOnClick(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
}
```

and error:

```
1>c:\users\lukasz\desktop\project\General.h(2204): error C3767: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::InvokeOnClick': candidate function(s) not accessible
1>c:\users\lukasz\desktop\project\General.h(2208): error C3767: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::InvokeOnClick': candidate function(s) not accessible
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: The `if`/`else if` branching doesn't make any sense. Was it intended?

Comment: after change checkbox state by clicking for example it'll do some functions and change state from uncheckd to checkd.
these if/else if is part of loading .xml backup file into program.

Comment: `Control::InvokeOnClick` is protected, calling it is a no-go. I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve that couldn't be done by setting the `checkBox1->Checked` property.

Comment: because i don't want to copy and paste function onClick the checkbox :P

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the greatest compiler error message.  But hard to blame it, you are maximizing the odds to confuse it hopelessly.  You are supposed to use the name of a member after `checkbox1->`.  Instead you specified a *class* name, Control.

Do avoid looking for ways to click a control from your code, that's something the user does.  The fact that InvokeOnClick isn't accessible is no accident.  The intention here is to set the Checked property.  So just set it:

```
 if (r->Value == "Off") checkBox1->Checked = false;
 else if (r->Value == "On") checkBox1->Checked = true;
```

with taking a guess at the original intent.

Comment: i don't want to run the same function like after click the checkbox, not just change checked status...

Comment: I cannot understand that comment, your English is different from mine.

Comment: Ehh.. i'm sorry... So... i want to run the same function like after clicking the checkbox (but it's private)

Comment: So call the function.  If this code isn't part of the form class (why?) then you need to make the function public.  I fail to see what this has to do with your original question, please start a new one.

Comment: ok, but how to call the function? I tried checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty); but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Control` should be the name of a class to be able to call its static member functions by means of `::`, but it's apparently not a class. Either `Control` is an object or a pointer to an object, I don't think you can use `::` with it. Just reasoning from the C++ perspective the question was (initially) tagged with.

Comment: sow how should i use it?
checkBox1::InvokeOnClick(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
?

Comment: @user1100671 Frankly, have no idea. Did you initially have a "C++" tag  there and now it's gone, removed by someone else? It's that tag which made me post this :P